# how to automatically create a class compatible with the access table?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

i want to use Linq to connect to a access2007 database (i don't want to use ado.net).

i saw some examples but all of them make a class of the object i want to import from the database for example

```
 public class Company
 {
     public string Name
     { get; set; }

     public List ListEmp
     { get; set; }
 }

var EmpDetails = from comp in ListCompany
                          select new
                          {
                              Emp = (from emp in comp.ListEmp
                                     select new { Company = comp.Name, emp })
                          };
```

thats is easy when u have a small database , but i have a database with 30 attribute in a table so it will be hard to make a class specifically for the object from the table

so is there a way easier like automatically create an object compatible with the objects from the table

if i wasn't clear please tell me so i could clarify it

thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, note that LINQ-to-SQL is not (AFAIK) validated for use on Access. It generally *works*, but MMMV.

Personally, I would approach this by importing (migrating) the tables from the Access database into a SQL Server Express instance, and using that to generate the model (of course, the tooling *might* even work against Access, but I assume they don't - hence the question). With the model generated, you should be able to point it (at runtime - via connection-string or connection) at your access database instead.

You might also consider: why not *leave* it as a SQL Server Express node - it works well, and is better supported in terms of LINQ-to-SQL.

Note also that there are other LINQ-to-SQL-like tools that may work for your purposes; DbLinq, dapper-dot-net, etc - and a few more heavy-weight tools (EF, NHibernate, LLBLGen Pro, etc)

Answer (score 1):

[XPO](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/ORM/), an ORM tool from [Developer Express](http://www.devexpress.com/), would allow you to create .Net classes directly from your Access 2007/2010 database and use [Linq](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XPO/CustomDocument4060) to create queries.

The good thing is that if you wish to change database backend, say for instance that you transferred your data from Access to [SQL Server or MySQL or PostgreSQL, etc](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XPO/CustomDocument2114) you just need to change the database connection string, not your code.

[Documentation is available online](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XPO/CustomDocument1998).